# How can I run TestNG Selenium tests remotely?

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, command-line, testng

I have Java project with TestNG tests and Selenium WebDriver. At the moment, I can run them locally from my IDE only.

**How can I implement a system that allows me to run a test with a post/get request on server?**

For example, a page with button: on button click, a test should start executing on server, with all WebDriver manipulations, and when it's finished, I would receive an answer.

At first, I tried to call my *testng.xml* from command line. It worked, but it looks like command line is not, what I can use remotely with simple FirefoxDriver, so I started researching the "RemoteWebDriver" feature.

Then I downloaded "*selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0*" and started the server and the node, but each time the script ends with an exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property
```

I added a required property, but it still doesn't work(the same problem). Here's a piece of code, which causes the exception:

```
@Test
public static void main() throws Exception {
    URL server = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    System.out.println("Connecting to " + server);
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(server, capabilities);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.quit();
}
```

As you see, the system property is set (geckodriver.exe exists in directory and works fine with FirefoxDriver, but doesn't work with RemoteWebDriver).

I don't understand, what I'm doing wrong, and not even sure, that I'm working in right direction. Can you help me,please?

Tried adding parameter, proposed by @ekostadinov. Here's how I start hub and node:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="geckodriver.exe" -jar lib\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub

java -jar lib\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Still doesn't work, but exception is different:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

**Update**

Changed this

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
```

To this

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
```

And it worked. Thanks everyone, who helped!

Comment: Try below link : http://executeautomation.com/blog/running-test-in-remote-machine-with-new-webdriver-functionality-grid-2-2/ might help.

Comment: Do you mean `Selenium Grid Hub` when you say `server`? Can you update the question with the commands you used to start the `Hub` & `Node`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to

> implement a system that allows me to run a test with a post/get request on server

except in the case, you **really** want to. [Continuous_integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) servers do all this and much more for you, out of the box. For example [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) (very suitable for JAVA based solutions) provides very convenient [Selenium plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin), which helps you to manage the Grid.

One thing to note here - you should pass additional parameters when starting the Hub on your server, like so:

```
 java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/full/path/to/chromedriver" -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="/full/path/to/geckodriver" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub
```

Comment: New parameters solved the problem with the exception, but now there is a new one `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities` . Do I need to pass capabilities as an argument as well? 

P.S.: I'll also try Jenkins. Thanks.

Comment: This Object should be passed from within your code, where you declare the `RemoteWebDriver` and should [be configured](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#remotewebdriver) based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this line of code above where you instantiate the driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
```

Like this

```
@Test
    public static void main() throws Exception {
    URL server = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    System.out.println("Connecting to " + server);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");        
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(server, capabilities);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.quit();
}
```

Also make sure the geckodriver is in the same directory where you are starting the hub/node.